# Access S3 bucket from a local docker container without AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

The bucket is publicly accessible, but with an ACL for access to only authorized users. I can access the S3 bucket from my local machine because I have AWS CLI configured for it.

Is there some way I can access the bucket from a docker instance running on my machine without having to install and configure AWS CLI on the docker image?

**EDIT:**
For those who do not understand how S3 works and are downvoting the question, a bucket can be publicly accessible - with all of its contents listed if the top level bucket URI is hit; and yet none of those items accessible because of ACL restrictions. I understand that may be a bad design, but that is not the point of this question.
I can access all of the items from my machine because I have AWS CLI configured to allow access to application AWS SDKs. I can however, not access them from Docker container.
It seems like that's not possible without setting up AWS CLI in the docker image because the SDKs either look for a configured AWS CLI, or try to hit the internal IP **169.254.169.254** for meta-data access, which succeeds in case of an EC2 instance. **And no, EC2 instances do not come with the CLI set up according to the answer below.** That is an IAM policy if your instances can access your protected S3 bucket.

Comment: There are about 10 different AWS SDK's available and any one of them could access an S3 bucket without the CLI.  Can you elaborate on what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: S3 objects can be accessible using HTTP request if the bucket is configured as public;  So I request you to make use of curl or wget which you can have it be default in any Linux docker container.

Answer (score -1):

All aws ec2 instances come prebuilt with the aws cli. If your docker containers are built with ec2 instances, you should not have to install the cli at all.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. I am interested in running the docker instance locally. So EC2 is out of the picture.